# Subset random points from spatial points data frame

Tags: r, subset, spatial, arcgis

I need to select random points in R from a grid I created in ArcGIS.

I have a Large SpatialPointsDataFrame with 160831 elements (points) named "gridpts". I imported the points with "readOGR"

```r
> names(gridpts)
[1] "gpts"   "L_code" "Lake"   "Area"
```

I want to subset the points by "L_code" and then select random points. This is what I have so far:

```r
acr2.pts    <- gridpts[gridpts$L_code == "acr2",]
sample.acr2 <- sample(nrow(acr2.grid), 690)
```

However, this gives me a vector with the gpts and not a subset of the points which is what I want.

Comment: Welcome! I assume this is R. Maybe it makes sense to mention that in the text (and title). It might also help to use the tag "R" as well.

Answer (score 0):

I make an assumption on your desired output.

I just use the `mtcars` dataset. Furthermore I use the `tidyverse`-package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- mtcars

n <- 3 # sample size; in your case 690
```

First of all, I want to subset the dataset on a given condition and pull a sample of size `n` from these subset:

```r
idx_sample <- df %>% 
                filter(cyl == 6) %>%  # in your case: L_code == "acr2"
                count() %>%           # count the datasets after subsetting; 7 in my case
                unlist %>%            # convert the tibble in to a vector  
                seq(1,.) %>%          # create a sequence, equal to 1:7 in my case
                sample(., n)          # get some (2 in my case) random indices
```

`idx_sample` contains the indizes of my sample of dataset after subsetting. Therefore

```r
df %>%
  filter(cyl == 6) %>%                # subset again
  slice(idx_sample)                   # get the sampled data
```

gives us the sampled subset.

Answer (score 0):

Spatialpointsdataframes work like regular dataframes, you can subset or select the rows and columns with square brackets e.g. [1:3,c(2,4,5)] for rows 1:3 of colums 2,4,5

after you already correctly subsetted your spdf to your desired subgroup:

```r
acr2.pts    <- gridpts[gridpts$L_code == "acr2",]
```

you need to subset again with your random samples:

```r
sample.acr2 <- sample(nrow(acr2.pts), 690)
```

(do you want to subset from the original number of rows or from the number of rows in your acr2 subset?)

this vector now contains the random row numbers, so you can select from the subset:

```r
random_sub <- acr2.pts[sample.acr2,]
```

Theoretically you could also already put the sample function in there, but that might look chaotic:

```r
random_sub <- acr2.pts[sample(nrow(acr2.pts), 690),]
```